# Prove a limit equals to $0$

Tags: limits

I need to prove that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty }{\frac 1n}\sin\left(\frac {n\pi}3\right) = 0.$$
This is what I did:
$$\left|{\frac 1n}\sin{\frac {n\pi}3}-0\right|<\epsilon,$$
$$|n|>{\frac {\sin{\frac {n\pi}3}}{\epsilon}},$$
$$ |n|>0,$$
but I think that my answer is not correct. Would you tell me whether my answer is right or not?

Comment: product of a null sequence with a bounded sequence is a null sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Archimedean property of the real numbers states that for all $\epsilon > 0$ one can always find  $N \in \mathbb{N}$ so that $\dfrac{1}{N} < \epsilon$. Now, since $| \sin \alpha | \leq 1 $ for all $\alpha$, then it must be the case that

$$ \left| \dfrac{1}{n} \sin \left( \dfrac{ n \pi }{3} \right) \right| \leq \dfrac{1}{n} $$

Now, Let $\epsilon > 0$ be arbitrary. Choose $N \in \mathbb{N}$ so that $\dfrac{1}{N} < \epsilon$. Therefore, for all $n > N$, one has

$$  \left| \dfrac{1}{n} \sin \left( \dfrac{ n \pi }{3} \right) \right| \leq \dfrac{1}{n} < \dfrac{1}{N} < \epsilon $$

In other words, $\lim \dfrac{1}{n} \sin \left( \dfrac{ n \pi }{3} \right) = 0$

$\textbf{Comments:}$

It is actually easier to use the squeeze rule to check this limit. This is a special case of the squeeze theorem. One can always rely on the definition and the archimedean property, but it is an o-v-e-r-k-i-l-l.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** $\left|\sin\left(\dfrac{n\pi}{3}\right)\right|\le 1$.